# Curious about the type of humour employed by Twitter's @AntiJokeCat?

Tags: formality, syntactic-analysis, humor, jokes, irony

Despite my general disregard for Twitter and its adherents, I very much enjoy AntiJokeCat's brand of humour. His/her gags are funny because they seem to subvert the notion of what a joke is and confound our expectations of what the punchline is going to be, usually in a dark way. Sometimes a genre joke e.g. a racist or sexist one is subverted at the last moment.

#### Some Examples

1. Yo momma's so stupid, she took an IQ test and scored pretty low on it.
2. Two muffins are in an oven. After ten minutes at 325 degrees, they were pulled out, allowed to cool, and then eaten.
3. What did the homeless man get for Christmas? Hypothermia.
4. What's yellow and good at Math? A yellow calculator.

More examples may be found at [AntiJokeCat's Twitter page](https://twitter.com/antijokecat).

Can anyone provide a <strike>better</strike> more academic classification of this type of humour aside from 'anti-joke'? I am detecting some `bathos` there at the very least.

And where did this deconstructionist humour originate?

Comment: I've heard them called *anti-jokes*.

Comment: They're all different.

Comment: *Bathos* involves an unexpected juxtaposition of the heroic or serious with the trivial or mundane. Same kind of idea, except this does not involve the heroic or serious, but rather the humorous.

Comment: The only *bathos* I can imagine here is if we allow that asking what a homeless man gets for Christmas is uplifting/serious. Which I can't really see, given that it's presented in the standard form of a one-liner joke, so you know before you get to it that the punchline is going to be amusing (or sick, depending on your point of view).

Comment: I belive `bathos` in its most general sense is a sudden change in style or tone, notably, but not exclusively, from the sublime to the prosaic. 'Antijokes' (for want of a better term) in the main *do* suddenly change tone or at least the tonal aspects of the form of the joke they  are subverting. I agree that all the examples I've offered *are* different, but they all serve to *deconstruct* the 'parent' jokes they are descended from.

Comment: @5arx: The sublime/ridiculous switch is common in jokes, so I don't think that helps identify the particular type you're talking about. Personally I don't see much point in the classification *anti-joke* anyway - I'd just say they're all **lame** and leave it at that.

Comment: My personal favorite:  The Pope, President Obama, and a boy scout walk into a bar; and the bartender says, "What is this, some kind of joke?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely anti-jokes. Wikipedia's article on it is very helpful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-humor

"Anti-humor is a type of indirect humor that involves the joke-teller delivering something which is deliberately not funny, or lacking in intrinsic meaning. The audience is expecting something humorous, and when this does not happen, the irony itself is of comedic value. "

Comment: I disagree. All OP's examples are different, as Matt says. But even though some people might say #3 is "in bad taste", it's just bog-standard "non-sequitur/misinterpretation/wordplay" humour. I don't think much of that Wikipedia page anyway, but that's hardly the point.

Comment: I'm saddened that there is no higher-level categorisation available other than the rather ugly and modern 'anti-joke' (they are not exactly *against* jokes are they ...?)